# Checking CSRF token inside a function

Tags: php

I have a user registration function and I want a CSRF token check inside the function. I haven't posted the whole function below because it's quite long, but I have put the important part in.

function user_register($link) {

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])) {

  if($_SESSION['form_token'] !== $_POST['form_token'])

echo "Tokens don't match";
```

This function generates the token:

```
function make_form_token() {
$token = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
$_SESSION['form_token'] = $token;
return $token;
} // end CSRF token generation
```

And the form has a hidden field with the token:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="register" value="Register">
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo $token ?>">
```

The tokens never match and I can't figure out why?

Comment: var_dump each token in your user_register function.

Comment: They are different. Which is my whole problem
CbC0zKITobzpKkTC5wBb2/nctb/DLGaJCDy/06ft2Io=
hpygRDqYeNz1dgPRr3LjpTqwv0AyVcx0ggE/9wb3H6Q=